# Does a Banach space always contain an element of arbitrarily large norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Or say, even just a normed linear space. Let $N \in \mathbb N$.

> Does there exist $x \in X $ with $\|x\| \ge N$?

If $X$ is a Banach space then its unit ball is also a Banach space so the answer should be no. But in [the proof of the Alaoglu theorem](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section9f.pdf) it is used that if we let $D_x = B(0,\|x\|) \subseteq \mathbb C$ then $\mathbb C = \bigcup_{x \in X} D_x$ and this seems to me requires that for every $N$ there is $x$ with $\|x\|\ge N$.

Comment: "If X is a Banach space then its unit ball is also a Banach space." No, its unit ball isn't even a vector space.

Comment: The unit ball is a complete metric space, but it is not a vector space (unless the space is the trivial space $\{ 0 \}$, in which case the unit ball is the whole space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\neq 0$ be any non-zero element, so that $\lVert x \rVert\neq 0$. Let $y=\dfrac{N}{\lVert x \rVert}x$. Then $\lVert y \rVert = N$. Right?

Comment: There is a Banach space though which doesn't contain any non-zero element ;)

Comment: @N.S.: Touché :)

Answer (score 4):

If $X \neq \{0\}$ is a normed space:

Take any $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$.  For any $N \in \Bbb N$, $\frac{N}{\|x\|}x$ has norm $N$. Remember that by definition, normed spaces are vector spaces.